# my pictures are never the same (shrinking and stretching) in CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm coding 3 boxes. There is pic and title at first column, then there is paragraph and at the bottom there is a link. So the boxes are not editable, just the content is. They should look the same no matter how long the title is. But the length of title changes size of pictures.

When the title needed more than one line, the pic shrank. So I added to my code a min-width. Now the ones previosly problematic are OK, but the third are wider than before, than the two other. Now the css code for pic looks like this. It is an icon with border (as you can see):

```
background-size: 40px 40px;
border: 2px solid $primary-green;
border-radius: 10px;
height: 56px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
min-width: 56px;
```

What should I add/change to make all 3 pics looks the same?

Structure:

```
<div class="box box--product">
    <div class="box__content">
        <div class="box__title d-flex">
            <div class="box__icon" style="background-image: url(\''.($atts['icon'] ? wp_get_attachment_image_src($atts['icon'], 'full')[0] : '').'\');"></div>
            <div class="box__icon box__icon--hover" style="background-image: url(\''.($atts['icon_hover'] ? wp_get_attachment_image_src($atts['icon_hover'], 'full')[0] : '').'\');"></div>
            <h3 class="box__hdl">'.$atts['nadpis'].'</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box__excerpt match-height">
            <p>'.$content.'</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box__more">
            <hr>
            <a href="'.$atts['url'].'" class="link-more">Viac informácií</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sass:

```
    .box {
    $this: &;

    background: $gray-lighter;
    border-bottom: 7px solid $primary-green;
    color: $black;
    cursor: pointer;
    //margin-bottom: $grid-gutter-width;

    &--not-hover {
        cursor: default;
    }


    &__title {
        align-items: center;

        &--subprod {
            margin-bottom: 16px;
            //min-height: 75px;
        }
    }

    &__more {
        text-align: center;
    }

    &__icon {
        background: {
            position: center;
            repeat: no-repeat;
            size: auto 44px;
        }
        border: 1px solid $gray-dark;
        border-radius: 5px;
        height: 80px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 80px;

        &--big {
            background-size: 65px auto;
            border-width: 2px;
            height: 112px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 112px;
        }

        &--hover {
            border-color: $white;
            display: none;
        }
    }
&__excerpt {
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: .44px;
        line-height: 21px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
&--product {
        border-bottom-width: 7px;

        #{$this}__hdl {
            color: $primary-green;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 20px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            text-transform: uppercase;

        }

        #{$this}__content {
            padding: 15px 22px 5px;
        }

        #{$this}__icon {
            background-size: 40px 40px;
            border: 2px solid $primary-green;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: 56px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            min-width: 56px;

            &--hover {
                border-color: $white;
            }
        }

        #{$this}__excerpt {
         //   border-bottom: 1px solid $primary-green;
            color: $gray-dark;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        #{$this}__more {
            .link-warning,
            .link-more {
                letter-spacing: .4px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
        }

        &:hover,
        &:focus {
            #{$this}__hdl {
                color: $white;
            }

            #{$this}__excerpt {
                border-bottom-color: $white;
            }

            #{$this}__more {
                .link-warning {
                    &::before {
                        background-image: url('../images/icon-warning--white.svg');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please include the html you are using highlighting the scenario you wished to behave differently?

Comment: Please include compiled CSS so we can see the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px; 
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.card .title {
  flex: 0 0 32px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.card .link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  flex: 0 0 32px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.card .image {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card .image img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="title">Some title</div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  </div>
  <div class="link">Some link</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="title">Some title that is way too long to fit in 200px</div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1024/768">
  </div>
  <div class="link">Some link that is also way too long for this little box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Notice that the images are respectively 200x300 & 1024x768

Comment: I added info for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not probably best practise. But I just add
`max-width: 57px;` (+1px)

and it works just fine.